# In Power BI, how to make relationships across common fields after pivoting columns

Tags: pivot, powerbi-desktop, slicers

In Power BI, the data is formatted so that category X is the name of the column but I needed to the category name to be part of the legend so I pivoted the column after duplicating that table.

In my visual, I needed a total revenue slicer that slices across charts using the original table and the duplicated table.

I tried connecting the revenue amounts (this was not one of the columns pivoted) between the table but this is where it got funky because of the pivoting. It's a many to many cardinality and a single cross functional direction and is not active.

Any suggestions on how to move forward?